# PHP :Making a curl request

Tags: php

I am having a problem Here

```
<?php 
        include('smsconfig.php');
        include("SMTPconfig.php");
        include("dbconnect.php");

        define("SITE_URL", "http://gf2fyu.blah.com");
        $GLOBAL_REST_URL = "gf2fyu.domain.com/organization/";

        $headers = array(
                        'X-MYDOMAIN-Secret:VuFlRQv40SUp0y1AXflMD0hWw8ZiiTu08f9ZXc0AYFc=',
                        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                        'Accept: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        );
        //$json = array2json($ages);
        $curl_handle=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$GLOBAL_REST_URL);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    //    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);
        $getit =  json_decode($buffer, true);
        $smskey =  substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,5);
        print_r($getit);
?>
```

The above code working fine for me if i am running it on my local server and mozila REST

client but whenever i am trying to put this code on production version

this code is  not hitting  the rest server .

Please tell me what is the problem here ?

I am using the same header in MOzila also it is working fine

I am running Nginx

Comment: Many servers have curl disabled. Have you tried `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: What do you mean "its not hitting server"? If you can't connect to the server, the code is moot. If you're hitting the page, but it's coming up blank, it's likely because `curl` is disabled and you're getting an error. Try commenting out the `curl` code to see if page loads.

Comment: @Dutchie432 I don't find replacing `cURL` with `file_get_Contents` good idea (lot of servers have `allow_url_wrappers` disables).

Comment: @Vyktor then alternatively, the user could find a host with `curl` :) I'm offering an alternative for testing.

Comment: @Dutchie432 if you need to send alternative headers, how would you do it with `file_get_contents()` (I'm not trying to be offensive, just exploring options that I may overlook in the time)

Comment: @Vyktor and Dutchie432 - You can add custom headers to file_get_contents using the context - third parameter in the call. But yes, as a general rule, get Curl to work and avoid relying on file_get_contents. You're both right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything really is in the comments, but let's put it down in order.

1) Curl may not be installed in the PHP on the server. To find out, turn on error reporting (or check error logs). Alternatively, a more robust way is to check for the function. Add the following to your code (just after the includes)

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
     die('Curl not installed');
}
```

Solution: you can try file_get_contents, but as noted in comments is it generally not recommended because this is also disabled. If you need to pass headers, you can do this in the "context" (third parameter in the call - check the manual). Better option is to install curl (or get support to install it).

2) There may be a firewall enabled. You can establish this by checking [curl_getinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)() and dumping the result to screen (for testing). This will tell you if it got blocked or made it through. See the manual for more info (linked above).

3) There may be an error higher up in your code that is causing problems. Check the error log, or turn on error_reporting with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Remember to remove those lines when you finally go into production, though.

Comment: You have teach me a good lesson to debug thanks  but really my problem was related to my nginx server